# Returning time of last modification of file to Stata

Tags: java, stata

I'm a Stata user trying to make use of Stata's [Java API](http://www.stata.com/java/api/). I want to use Java to return the time of last modification of a file to Stata. However, I think I'm running into issues with time zones.

**Quick background on times in Stata for non-Stata users:** Times are represented by the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1960 00:00:00.000`. Stata does not have time zones, so I want the return value from the Java function to be the number of milliseconds since midnight on `January 1, 1960` in my time zone (America/New York).

Here is my attempt at the Java function (I can post it in its entirety if that would be helpful):

```
import com.stata.sfi.*;
// Other imports

public class SFileAttribs
{
    // Syntax: lastModified(String filename, String scalar_name)
    // Stores in the Stata scalar scalar_name the time of last
    // modification of filename.
    public static int lastModified(String[] args)
    {
        // Code here...

        // Get the time.
        FileTime time;
        try {
            time = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(path, "lastModifiedTime");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            SFIToolkit.errorln("file I/O error on read");
            return(692);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }

        // Store the time in the scalar.
        Calendar cal1960 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1960.set(1960, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        cal1960.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Scalar.setValue(args[1], time.toMillis() - cal1960.getTimeInMillis());

        return(0);
    }
}
```

Back in Stata, I run this command:

```
// Calls SFileAttribs.lastModified("Test.txt", "filetime").
javacall SFileAttribs lastModified, args("Test.txt" "filetime")
```

However, the result is an hour earlier than it should be:

```
. display %tc filetime
24oct2013 12:54:36
```

The time of last modification in my time zone is `13:54`, not `12:54`.

I am really struggling on this one and would appreciate any suggestions.

---

**EDIT:**

Perhaps predictably given that I'm coming from a language with no time zones, I think I messed up daylight savings. In my time zone, it is now DST, but in the same time zone in `January 1, 1960`, it was not DST. I need to account for that:

```
// Store the time in the scalar.
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal1960 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1960.set(1960, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
cal1960.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
int dstHour = (cal1960.getTimeZone().inDaylightTime(cal1960.getTime()) ? 1 : 0) -
        (now.getTimeZone().inDaylightTime(now.getTime()) ? 1 : 0);
cal1960.set(Calendar.HOUR, dstHour);
Scalar.setValue(args[1], time.toMillis() - cal1960.getTimeInMillis());
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The *community-contributed* command `filesys` is the easiest way to do exactly what you want:

```
. findfile auto.dta
. filesys `r(fn)', attributes

. return list

macros:
(some output omitted)

        r(accessednum) : "1871843910000"
        r(modifiednum) : "1745362526000"
         r(creatednum) : "1745362526000"
           r(accessed) : "25apr2019 20:38:30"
           r(modified) : "22apr2015 22:55:26"
            r(created) : "22apr2015 22:55:26"

. display %tcHH:MM `r(modifiednum)'  
22:55
```

You can install the `filesys` command by using the 
*community-contributed* command `github`:

```
. net install github, from("https://haghish.github.io/github/")
. github install wbuchanan/StataFileSystem
```